# Why don't multiple items fit vertically in the React native View?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, view, scroll

I have an App in which there is a View with two CardViews that each direct me to different screens.

Now I have added another CardView, and there are already three.
The problem is that neither in iOS nor in Android the third of the CardView is shown in full, only part of it is shown as I show in the screenshot.

I have tried ScrollView since it is a list of few items and Scroll works, but it does not stop and when I release my finger from the screen, the screen returns to its initial position.
Also the scroll does the entire screen, including the Header, which should not be the case
I have also tried using FlatList, but I get errors

I have played with the View styles, but I do not understand the problem that is offered so that the Scroll does not work within the View.

I show the code of the file, with the third of the CardView added.
How can I correct this and make the screen Scroll to be able to access all the CardViews on the screen?

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import _ from "lodash"
import ToolBar from "../../../component/ToolBar";
import styleApp from "../../../../res/style/style";
import AppText from "../../../component/Text";
import { strings } from "../../../config/i18n/i18n";
import CardView from "../../../component/CardView";

import { sizeWidth } from "../../../util/Size";
import NavigationActions from "../../../router/NavigationActions"
import {
  AsyncStorage,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  List,
  SectionList
} from "react-native"

export default class PaintScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    studiedAlphabet: [],
    studiedNumber: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((error, keys) => {
      AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (error, stores) => {
        const alphabets = [];
        const numbers = [];
        stores.map((result, i, store) => {
          // get at each store's key/value so you can work with it
          if (store[i] != null) {
            //data provide is [key: value] - value [[]]
            if (store[i][0] == "learned_alphabets") {
              alphabets.push(JSON.parse(store[i][1]));
            }

            if (store[i][0] == "learned_numbers") {
              numbers.push(JSON.parse(store[i][1]));
            }
          }
          if (i == keys.length - 1) {
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              studiedAlphabet: alphabets[0],
              studiedNumber: numbers[0]
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoading) {
      return (

        <View style={styles.containerMio}>

          <Image
            style={styles.backgroundImage}
            source={require("../../../../res/images_paint/background/backgroundA_2x.png")}
          />
          <Image
            style={styles.newPaintImage}
            source={require("../../../../res/images_paint/mainScreen/new_paint_ball_2x.png")}
          />

          {this.renderToolbar()}

          <View
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              alignItems: "center",
              position: "absolute",
              top: sizeWidth(20)
            }}
          >

            {this.renderAnimal()}
            {this.renderObject()}
            {this.renderAnimal()}

          </View>
    
        </View>

      )
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  renderToolbar = () => {
    return (
      <ToolBar
        center={
          <AppText style={styleApp.ToolBarText}>
            {strings("paint.title")}
          </AppText>
        }
      />
    );
  };

  renderAnimal = () => {
    return (
      <CardView
        image={require("../../../../res/images_paint/newPaintingScreen/animals_2x.png")}
        styleImg={styles.styleAnimal}
        title={strings("paint.animals")}
        backgroundColor={"#fff989"}
        colorButton={"#FE6230"}
        onPress={() =>
          NavigationActions.navigate("PaintAnimals", {
            studiedNumber: this.state.studiedNumber,
            studiedAlphabet: this.state.studiedAlphabet
          })
        }
      />
    );
  }

  renderObject = () => {
    const { studiedAlphabet } = this.state;

    return (
      <CardView
        image={require("../../../../res/images_paint/newPaintingScreen/object_2x.png")}
        styleImg={styles.styleObject}
        title={strings("paint.objects")}
        backgroundColor={"#B29FFF"}
        colorButton={"#FE6230"}
        onPress={() =>
          NavigationActions.navigate("PaintObjects", {
            studiedNumber: this.state.studiedNumber,
            studiedAlphabet: this.state.studiedAlphabet
          })
        }
      />
    );
  }

  renderAnimal = () => {
    return (
      <CardView
        image={require("../../../../res/images_paint/newPaintingScreen/animals_2x.png")}
        styleImg={styles.styleAnimal}
        title={strings("paint.animals")}
        backgroundColor={"#fff989"}
        colorButton={"#FE6230"}
        onPress={() =>
          NavigationActions.navigate("PaintAnimals", {
            studiedNumber: this.state.studiedNumber,
            studiedAlphabet: this.state.studiedAlphabet
          })
        }
      />
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },

  containerMio: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    resizeMode: "stretch",
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  },
  newPaintImage: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  },
  styleAnimal: {
    resizeMode: "center",
    width: sizeWidth(70),
    height: sizeWidth(50),
    marginLeft: sizeWidth(-5),
  },
  styleObject: {
    resizeMode: "center",
    width: sizeWidth(70),
    height: sizeWidth(50),
    marginLeft: sizeWidth(-5),
  }
})
```

Comment: Try giving flex:1 to all 3 cardviews.

Comment: I have tried and it does not work. Maybe I'm not doing it correctly, Styles are not my specialty. This is what I did, is that what you mean? I don't know any other way: `<CardView
      style={{flex: 1}}
        image={require("../../../../res/images_paint/newPaintingScreen/animals_2x.png")}
        styleImg={styles.styleAnimal}
        title={strings("paint.animals")}
        backgroundColor={"#fff989"}
        colorButton={"#FE6230"}
          })
        }
      />`    I also added it to the global styles, unsuccessfully. I do not know what to do